# fb comments-count throwing an error in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, api, plugins, comments, facebook-social-plugins

We're having a problem with the facebook comments-count plugin in conjunction with the comments plugin. The pair works great for us in FF/Chrome, but we're unable to get the count to work properly in IE.

The comments box loads fine, but I find the following error for the count:

```
FB.ApiServer._callbacks.f25a446b05aa0da({"error_code":"601","error_msg":"Parser error: unexpected ':' at position 58.","request_args":[{"key":"callback","value":"FB.ApiServer._callbacks.f25a446b05aa0da"},{"key":"format","value":"json-strings"},{"key":"method","value":"fql.multiquery"},{"key":"pretty","value":"0"},{"key":"queries","value":"{\"index_link_stat_url\":\"select url,commentsbox_count from link_stat where url=http:\/\/www.wor710.com\/pages\/10825674.php\"}"},{"key":"sdk","value":"joey"}]});
```

For the particular URL in question, this should be resulting in a "0" value for the count.